# Подсчет тысяч в числе

Tags: php

Из чего можно слепить функцию подсчета тысяч в числе, чтобы вывести:

```
2000 -> 2k
1456 -> 1,4k
587 -> 587
```

Comment: Покажите ваши варианты и почему они вас не устраивают.

Comment: Ну вот кто будет уточнять подробности, если уже есть принятый ответ? Да и вопрос вполне понятный. Что за желание всё подряд закрывать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$num  = 1200;
$base = 1000;
echo ($num >= $base ) ? round($num / $base, 1).'k' : $num;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function okr($x) {
    $base = 1000;

    if ($x >= $base*100) {
        return round($x / ($base*100), 1).'M';
    }

    if($x >= $base) {
        return round($x / $base, 1).'k';
    }

    return $x;
}


var_dump(okr(1200));
var_dump(okr(1200000));
```

результат

```
string '1.2k' (length=4)
string '12M' (length=3)
```